# Stable equilibrium in a gravitational field with 2 masses

Tags: forces, equilibrium

Suppose you have two point masses $M_1, M_2$ in space and you locate the point $A$ on the line between them such that an object placed at $A$ is in equilibrium (the only forces acting on the obect are the gravitational forces from each point mass). Apparently $A$ is an unstable equilibrium for points along the line joining $M_1,M_2$, but a stable equilibrium for points along  the line passing through $A$ and perpindicular to the line joining $M_1,M_2$.

How can check this (1) intuitively and (2) mathematically?

Comment: I can't understand what you ask: "Apparently A  is an unstable equilibrium for points along the line joining $M_1,M_2$, but a stable equilibrium for points along the line passing through A  and perpindicular to the line joining $M_1,M 2$." Is A in equilibrium, or not? And what is the role of the line perpendicular to the line $M_1M_2$?

Comment: By equilibrium, I mean a point such that the net force due to the two masses are 0. A is an equilibrium point of the system of two masses. When I say $A$ is unstable for points along the line $M_1M_2$, it means an object placed along this line will not oscillate about $A$ (it will move towards $M_1$ or $M_2$). $A$ is stable for the perpindicular because an object placed along this line will tend to oscillate about $A$. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium#Stability

Comment: No, what you say is not completely exact. I mean, the object A won't be I equilibrium at any point on the line $M_1M_2$. As a simple example, if $M_1 > M_2$ and the object is closer to $M_1$, it will fall on $M_1$. But this would be the fate of the object A also if it is placed on a line perpendicular to the line $M_1M_2$. If it is closer to the bigger mass, it will fall on it. On the other side, there in something true in your idea of a perpendicular line. Please see my answer. I need formulas, and they don't fit in the space of a comment. I am editing the answer now.

Comment: $A$ is not an object, it is a point such that an object placed at the point will be in equilibrium!

Comment: Are $M_1$ and $M_2$ fixed in space ([Euler's three-body problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_three-body_problem)), or are they orbiting one another, or are you ignoring the orbital motion (getting back to Euler's two fixed centers)? It makes a big difference. If they're orbiting, then you should accept rob's answer. If they're not (or if you are ignoring that), this is a different problem. BTW, is this homework?

Comment: They are fixed in space. This is not HW. This was a component in a solution to some problem, and the claim was made without proof. I really hate when Stack Exchange blocks a question that actually does relate to a specific concept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, your point $A$ is the first [Lagrange point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point), L1.  The other unstable points L2, L3 are infinitely far away in the absence of angular momentum.

$A$ is an unstable equilibrium because it is a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) in the overall potential
$$
\frac {U(\vec x)}{-G} = \frac{M_1}{|\vec x_1 -\vec x|} + \frac{M_2}{|\vec x_2 -\vec x|}
$$
In the special case where $M_1=M_2$, there is a plane midway between the two masses where the force $\vec F = -\nabla U$ points towards neither mass; however trajectories along this plane aren't stable, either, and small perturbations will send a mass towards one point or another.

If the masses $M_1\neq M_2$ are unequal there is not such a plane. 
Instead there is a paraboloid where the potential energy due to $M_1$ and $M_2$ is the same, as Sofia has shown, whose vertex is your point $A$.
As the ratio between the two masses gets farther from unity, the volume of space where you can reasonably talk about "trajectories that head towards $A$" gets smaller and smaller.  This is probably related to the fact that the stability of the Lagrangian points L4 and L5 requires the ratio $M_1/M_2 \gtrsim 25$.

Comment: BTW I forgot to mention to consider everything in the plane of $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Comment: @rob, didn't you see my answer? what you sais that I didn't say?

Comment: @Sofia You and I were writing at the same time … you seemed to have the "mathematical" answer, while I had a more "intuitive" answer.

Comment: @Rob , very well, then Joshua will have now all the types of explanations. Very well.

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrium line perpendicular on the line $M_1M_2$ is the given by the equation

$G\frac {M_1 M_A cos(\theta_1)}{|\vec r_{M_1,A}|^2} = G\frac {M_2 M_A cos(\theta_2)}{|\vec r_{M_2,A}|^2}$

where $\theta_1$ is the angle between the line $M_1A$ and the line $M_1M_2$, while $\theta_2$ is the angle between the line $M_2A$ and the line $M_1M_2$.

Thus, the desired equilibrium line is given by the relation

(1) $\frac {M_1 cos(\theta_1)}{|\vec r_{M_1,A}|^2} = \frac {M_2 cos(\theta_2)}{|\vec r_{M_2,A}|^2}$.

For the moment I don't know if it is a straight line, so let me introduce new variables

$cos(\theta_1) = x, \ \ \ cos(\theta_1) = L - x$,

where $L$ is the distance $M_1M_2$.

$|\vec r_{M_1,A}|^2 = x^2 + y^2, \ \ \ |\vec r_{M_2,A}|^2 = (L- x)^2 + y^2$,

where $y$ is the distance on vertical between the point $A$ and the line $M_1M_2$.
Introducing all this in (1)

(2) $\frac {M_1 x}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac {M_2 (L - x)}{(L- x)^2 + y^2}$.

Simplifying a bit,

(3) $M_1 x [(L - x)^2 + y^2] = M_2 (L - x)[x^2 + y^2]$.

Moving everything to the left-hand-side,

(4) $M_1(x^3 -2Lx^2 + L^2x + xy^2) + M_2(x^3 - Lx^2 + xy^2 - Ly^2) = 0$,

from which we get the curve

$x^3 - (1 + \frac{M_1}{M_1 + M_2})Lx^2 + \frac{M_1}{M_1 + M_2}L^2x + (x - \frac {M_2}{M_1 + M_2} L)y^2 = 0$.

It's not a straight line. One would be tempted to ask whether the vertical $x = \frac {M_2}{M_1 + M_2}L$ could be the sought vertical. The answer is no, unless $M_1 = M_2$.